# pytest html report generation

Tags: html, report, pytest, pytest-html

I'm trying to use pytest-html plugin to generate the html report from py.test runs,

```
@pytest.fixture()
def get_requests_info():
 ....
 return [(0,'request1'),(1,'request2')]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("request", get_requests_info())
    def test_a_vs_b(request):
     .....
```

How should i set the environment fixture to create the html reports?

If I simply add,

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _environment(request):
    request.config._environment.append(('foo'))
```

I'm getting error like,

```
    @pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
    def environment(request):
        """Provide environment details for HTML report"""
>       request.config._environment.extend([
            ('Python', platform.python_version()),
            ('Platform', platform.platform())])
E       AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a fixture named `request` which clashes with pytest's builtin `request` fixture. I'd recommend just calling your fixture something else.